# How do I make div elements hover in reverse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

First, let's review my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="button_container">
    <div class="inner_button">
        <a href="#" class="button_text">Button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button_side">
        <i class="play" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner_button:hover {
    background: red;
}
.button_container:hover > .button_side { 
    background-color: red !important; 
}
```

The above code will let `.button_side` hover if `.button_container` is hovered.  But now I also want to do the reverse, so that if `.button_side` is hovered it will hover `.button_container`.  I believe with CSS it will be difficult but I would prefer it but I am open to something in JQuery.  How can I do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate with a screen shot how you want them to look?

Comment: it is possible with css only if button_container would be a child of button_side. css->cascade means you can only cascade from parents to children. if you don't change your html it is only possible with javascript

Answer (score 4):

> *"I also want to do the reverse, so that if `.button_side` is hovered it will hover `.button_container`"*

I believe you are correct about needing to use JS for this (easy with some jQuery), because CSS tends to work from parents to children, not the other way around. First define a class to add with the desired setting(s):

```
.hover {
    background : red;
}
```

And then:

```
$(".button_side").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).closest(".button_container").addClass("hover");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).closest(".button_container").removeClass("hover");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PxQCT/

Within a jQuery event handler, `this` (usually) refers to the element that the event applied to, so `$(this)` gives you a jQuery wrapper to the hovered item and lets you use jQuery's `.closest()` method to find the nearest ancestor with the `.button_container` class.

Note that the JS code that I've shown would need to be included in a script element that appears after the elements in question, and/or in a document ready handler.

EDIT / P.S.: Note that in your markup as shown in the question the `.button_side` element doesn't actually have any hoverable content, just an empty (self-closing) `<i>` element (so in my demo I added some content there so that you could have something to hover over and see it working).

Comment: +1. You beat me by 25 seconds :) and better in the sense that you put the hover only on the closest container.

Comment: I was writing my own answer, but this one sums it up pretty well. It would be possible using 3 CSS rules (using `:not()`), but that would be ugly and unnecessary, so your answer is correct.

Comment: @ramsesoriginal with css4 you can use `E! > F` but I think we need to wait some years until this is widely supported -.-

Comment: I know, it's the feature i wait for the most. Give me that and a previous sibling selector, and I'm happy.

Comment: Thanks but if i hover button it doesn't hover play.  I also want the div that holds "play" to be next to the div that holds "play."Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are asking but probably helpful.

Sometimes is a suitable solution if you don't want to mess around with js to much.
On the other side it makes your `html` and `css` code messy. I rarely use this in some special situations (e.g. for having a hover effect for column views where the column can have a height of 100% because it should expand the row).

It does not work for older IE versions so if it is used it should be used with caution.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="button_container">
     <div class="inner_button">
         <a href="#" class="button_text">Button</a>
     </div>
     <div class="button_side">
         <i class="play">play</i>
         <div class="hover-fake"><div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hover-fake {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    display: none;
}

.button_container {
    position: relative;
    left: 0xp;
    top: 0px;
}

.inner_button:hover {
    background: red;
}
.button_container:hover > .button_side { 
    background-color: red !important; 
}

.button_side:hover > .hover-fake  {
    display: block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65yuA/)**

Comment: THanks.  This seems more like it.  Can you put them next to each other instead of on top of each other?

Comment: @ariel I changed the code but not sure if this is really what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/65yuA/1/

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can do something like this (with jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button_side').hover(function(){
        $('.button_container').addClass('hover');        
    }, function(){
        $('.button_container').removeClass('hover');
    });

});
```

If you need some help, try to see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59YqL/).